# using split view how to load web view in detail view

Tags: detailsview, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

how to initialise my detail view with webview when a table row get selected in master view...
any example or any method to solve this problem....

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize one UIWebview in Detailview('s loadview)  and Keep it as hidden. If a row is tapped on master controler then pass that URL to UIWebView and make it as Visible.

All the best!!

Answer (score 0):

in TableView method didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        NSURL *urlStrg= [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlStrg];
        [self.detailViewController.detailItem loadRequest:urlRequest];
    }else if(indexPath.row == 1) {
//do something else here

}
```